# Docker for development - Watch/Auto build?

Tags: vagrant, docker, boot2docker

I'm trying to move from Vagrant to Docker, or Vagrant+Docker.
Trying to figure out the best solution... anyway this is my workflow for development.

- 1) Build vm environment
- 2) Share synced folder
- 3) Develop
- 4) Test directly in browser

Code is refreshed automatically within the vm, so I can check the app as I make changes to it.

---

With Docker is seems a bit different, as the `build` command needs to be run each time a change is made.

**Any way that `build` can be run as soon as a change is detected?**

---

**Any recommendations for using Docker for development?**

Comment: Fig (http://www.fig.sh/) is a great tool for development with docker.

Comment: I've made http://dockershell.io/ for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

In docker, **volumes** are the counterpart to vagrant synced folders. A volume should perfectly fit to your use case:

https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build an image as soon as a change is made then I recommend using [Automated Builds](http://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/).

I'm moving also to Vagrant+Docker, here are some links that helped me understanding how everything works.

- https://blog.abevoelker.com/rails-development-using-docker-and-vagrant/
- http://www.talkingquickly.co.uk/2014/06/rails-development-environment-with-vagrant-and-docker/

I also recommend trying [CoreOS](https://coreos.com/) with Vagrant.